# How do I disable the Performance Explorer from opening every time?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

On a project that you've ran a Performance Analysis, the Performance Explorer tab always opens when VS is started, even if it was closed just before VS was exited.

How do I disable it and keep it from opening?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

This is actually BUG since [Visual Studio 2012](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/749636/performance-explorer-window-is-always-opened-when-vs-is-started-and-mr-soln-opens#tabs) that's been open since summer 2012 with still no official MS fix.

Here's a workaround to this annoyance:

1. From Windows explorer, go under your VS project folder
2. Remove the following file types if present:

   - file.vsp - (VS Performance Report)
   - file.vsps - (VS Analyzed Reports)
   - file.psess - (VS Performance Session)
3. Re-open the Solution, if error, click OK (the Solution will still load)
4. Close the solution
5. Re-open the solution - the Performance Explorer tab will be finally gone!

   ---

   @B. Clay Shannon - thanks for update to also delete *.vsps

Comment: I can't find these files

Comment: @HảiPhong the files should be located under your solution's folder

Comment: Also, as a side note. In the case (which I was) that you've accidentally committed the .vsp/.psess files to your code repository, these files will be brought down every time you update. Un-version/add to ignore -- or whatever your repo's method is -- so that they don't return.

Comment: Still exists in 2013.

Comment: Can't believe something this simple isn't fixed yet. Thank you! Works great.

Comment: When I did the remove step from the file system directly, it kept coming back.  When I did a right-click => "Remove" in VS, it stayed gone for good.

Comment: @LarsTech - I've marked it. Thank you for the pointer.  I'm glad this is helping folks out there.  Thanks everyone for your kind words.

Comment: after you do performance analysis, a couple of sections are getting added in the `sln` solution file. Fortunately, i was in version control and i was able to locate them and get rid of them. Also deleted the `vsp` and `psess` files. Now everything is 100% back to normal. p.s. vs2013

Comment: When I (VS 2013) removed several *.psess files (and .vsps), on reopening the app I got, "Performance Session file <bla.psess" does not exist or is invalid" And then the Performance Explorer came up, anyway. I had to also delete two *.vsps files before it would open without nagging me and still resurrecting the rigormortasified Performance Explorer pane.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon - thanks I've updated the answer to include *.vsps

Comment: I also had to delete a `.vspscc` file in VS 2015. The file came back, but not the performance explorer finally stays in its cage

Answer (score 4):

In VS2015 Update 1 deleting the .psess file as per Leonel Gurdian's answer doesn't seem to work. Changing `true` to `false` in the following part of the .sln file did the trick though.

```
GlobalSection(Performance) = preSolution
    HasPerformanceSessions = true
EndGlobalSection
```

Answer (score 1):

And it is still there in VS 2015 RC! You have to chose more options to start Performance Explorer but if it's once opened, it comes again each time you start IDE atleast when you open your project.

But deleting the psess-file in ProjectFolder still works.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on all items in 'performance explorer', choose 'Remove' and confirm the dialog boxes. After restarting Visual Studio, it will be gone